# enumerados sincronizados

Tags: c++

Supongamos un escenario en el que dos enumerados deben estar sincronizados:

```
// Este enumerado necesita los valores porque se almacenan en la base de datos
enum class Enum1
{
  A = 12,
  B = 4,
  C = 5,
};

// Este enumerado es necesario para realizar tareas de iteración
// y porque si :)
enum class Enum2
{
  NoValue,
  A,
  B,
  C,
  MaxValues
};
```

Además, nos encontramos con un catálogo de funciones de utilidad que aprovechan estos enumerados:

```
// Convierte cada etiqueta en su representación a string
std::string ToString(Enum1 valor)
{
  switch( valor )
  {
    case Enum1::A: return "A";
    case Enum1::B: return "B";
    case Enum1::C: return "C";
  }

  return "";
}

Enum1 FromString(std::string const& valor)
{
  if( valor == "A" ) return Enum1::A;
  if( valor == "B" ) return Enum1::B;
  if( valor == "C" ) return Enum1::C;

  throw std::runtime_exception("valor no valido");
}

Enum1 Convert(Enum2 value)
{
  switch( value )
  {
    case Enum2::A: return Enum1::A;
    case Enum2::B: return Enum1::B;
    case Enum2::C: return Enum1::C;
  }

  throw std::runtime_exception("valor no valido");
}

// ...
```

¿Existe alguna forma más elegante de mantener los enumerados sincronizados?

Lo ideal sería que la solución aplicada también permitiese evitar el coste asociado a editar manualmente las funciones de utilidad cada vez que se añaden / eliminan valores a los enumerados.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### El problema.

El problema de *sincronizar* cosas es que generalmente no se puede hacer de manera automática, el usuario suele ser el encargado de especificar cómo se relaciona cada entidad; este punto de personalización suele ser inevitable y hacer que sea lo más cómodo posible y no propenso a errores es la parte complicada.

#### Propuesta.

Cuando me tuve que enfrentar a un problema similar usé plantillas variádicas (C++11) y variables plantilla (C++14). Empezamos por generar un mapa que asocia los tipos, yo uso variables plantilla:

```
template <typename ENUM>
std::map<ENUM, const std::string> nombre_enum{};

template <typename ENUM>
std::map<const std::string, ENUM> valor_enum{};

template <typename ENUM1, typename ENUM2>
std::map<ENUM1, ENUM2> asocia{};
```

Con estas variables plantilla declaradas, añadimos unas funciones de inicialización:

```
void nombra() {}

template <typename ENUM, typename ... args>
void nombra(const ENUM value, const char *name, args ... tail)
{
    nombre_enum<ENUM>.emplace(value, name);
    valor_enum<ENUM>.emplace(name, value);
    nombra<ENUM>(tail ...);
}

void sincroniza() {}

template <typename ENUM1, typename ENUM2, typename ... args>
void sincroniza(const ENUM1 value1, const ENUM2 value2, args ... tail)
{
    asocia<ENUM1, ENUM2>.emplace(value1, value2);
    sincroniza(tail ...);
}
```

Con estas funciones de inicialización<sup>1</sup>, debemos configurar el sistema:

```
int main()
{
    nombra
    (
        Enum1::A,         "Doce",
        Enum1::B,         "Cuatro",
        Enum1::C,         "Cinco",
        Enum2::NoValue,   "Sin valor",
        Enum2::A,         "Uno",
        Enum2::B,         "Dos",
        Enum2::C,         "Tres",
        Enum2::MaxValues, "Máximo de Enum2"
    );

    sincroniza
    (
        Enum1::A, Enum2::A,
        Enum1::B, Enum2::B,
        Enum1::C, Enum2::C
    );
    return 0;
}
```

Y esto nos permite cambiar las funciones `ToString`, `FromString` y `Convert` de la siguiente manera:

```
template <typename ENUM>
std::string ToString(ENUM valor)
{
    std::string result{};
    auto found = nombre_enum<ENUM>.find(valor);

    if (found != nombre_enum<ENUM>.end()) result = found->second;

    return result;
}

template <typename ENUM>
ENUM FromString(std::string const& nombre)
{
    ENUM result{};
    auto found = valor_enum<ENUM>.find(nombre);

    if (found != valor_enum<ENUM>.end()) result = found->second;
    else throw std::runtime_error("valor no valido");

    return result;
}

template <typename ENUM1, typename ENUM2>
ENUM1 Convert(ENUM2 value)
{
    ENUM1 result{};
    auto found = asocia<ENUM2, ENUM1>.find(value);

    if (found != asocia<ENUM2, ENUM1>.end()) result = found->second;
    else throw std::runtime_error("valor no valido");

    return result;
}
```

Y en consecuencia:

```
ToString(Enum1::A);        // Devuelve la cadena "Doce".
FromString<Enum1>("Doce"); // Devuelve Enum1::A.
FromString<Enum2>("Doce"); // Lanza una excepcion.
Convert<Enum1>(Enum2::A);  // Lanza una excepcion.
Convert<Enum2>(Enum1::A);  // Devuelve Enum2::A.
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando En <kbd>[Wandbox 三へ( へ՞ਊ ՞)へ ﾊｯﾊｯ](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Y2i9Hq6JvllHZUKZ)</kbd>.

#### Pros y contras.

**Pro**: Usando variables plantilla el propio compilador se encarga de sincronizar los mapas `nombre_enum`, `valor_enum` y `asocia` entre cada [unidad de traducción [image]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)). De hecho, existirá una sola copia por cada tipo o combinación de tipos usados en la plantilla, esto se debe a la regla de definición única de C++ y cómo esta regla funciona con las plantillas, según el [estándar de C++](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) (resaltado y traducción mías):

> #### 3.2 Regla de definición única
>
> 5. **Se requiere exáctamente una definición de una clase en una unidad de traducción** si dicha clase es usada de manera que su tipo necesite estar completo.
>
>    [...]
> 6. **Puede haber más de una definición** del tipo de una clase (Cláusula 9), tipo enumerado (7.2), función en línea con enlazado externo (7.1.2), clase plantilla (Cláusula 14), función plantilla no estática (14.5.6), datos miembro de una clase plantilla (14.5.1.3), función miembro de una clase plantilla (14.5.1.1), o especialización de plantilla para la que algunos parámetros plantilla no están especificados (14.7, 14.5.5) **en un programa en que cada definición aparezca en diferentes unidades de traducción**, [...]
>
>    [...]
>
>    **Si D es una plantilla y se define en más de una unidad de traducción,** [...], **entonces se comportará como si hubiera una única definición de D**.

**Contra**: El punto anterior implica que cada una de las variables plantillas se comporta como una variable global y puede ser peligroso su uso en código multihilo. Pero a priori, tras la llamada a `nombra` y `sincroniza` no es necesario escribir más en los mapas, por lo tanto su uso a través de `ToString`, `FromString` y `Convert` sería de sólo lectura.

**Pro**: En el momento de insertar nuevos valores a los enumerados, se ha reducido la necesidad de cambios de 4 (el enumerado y las funciones `ToString`, `FromString` y `Convert`) a 3 (el enumerado y el punto de personalización en `nombra` y `sincroniza`).

---

<sup>1</sup>En C++17 nos podemos ahorrar la función vacía de ruptura de la recursión usando el condicional constante `if constexpr`:

```
template <typename ENUM, typename ... args>
void nombra(const ENUM value, const char *name, args ... tail)
{
    nombre_enum<ENUM>.emplace(value, name);
    valor_enum<ENUM>.emplace(name, value);

    if constexpr (sizeof...(tail) >= 2)
    {
        nombra<ENUM>(tail ...);
    }
}

template <typename ENUM1, typename ENUM2, typename ... args>
void sincroniza(const ENUM1 value1, const ENUM2 value2, args ... tail)
{
    asocia<ENUM1, ENUM2>.emplace(value1, value2);

    if constexpr (sizeof...(tail) >= 2)
    {
        sincroniza(tail ...);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

El primer paso es crear un nuevo fichero, por ejemplo `valores.def` y movemos a dicho fichero los valores del enumerado:

```
A = 12,
B = 4,
C = 5,
```

Ahora editamos ese fichero para encerrar cada valor en una macro. Para evitar errores futuros definimos una implementación base de dicha macro y su posterior limpieza:

```
#ifndef VALOR
#define VALOR(X,Y)
#endif

VALOR(A,12)
VALOR(B,4)
VALOR(C,5)

#undef VALOR
```

Ahora generamos los enumerados a partir de dicho fichero. Para ello basta simplemente con configurar la macro a conveniencia:

```
enum class Enum1
{
  #define VALOR(X,Y) X=Y,
  #include "valores.def"
};

enum class Enum2
{
  NoValue,
  #define VALOR(X,Y) X,
  #include "valores.def"
  MaxValues
};
```

Y lo mismo para la batería de utilidades:

```
std::string ToString(Enum1 valor)
{
  switch( valor )
  {
    #define VALOR(X,Y) case Enum1::##X: return #X;
    #include "valores.def"
  }

  return "";
}

Enum1 FromString(std::string const& valor)
{
  #define VALOR(X,Y) if( valor == #X ) return Enum1::##X;
  #include "valores.def"

  throw std::runtime_exception("valor no valido");
}

Enum1 Convert(Enum2 value)
{
  switch( value )
  {
    #define VALOR(X,Y) case Enum2::##X: return Enum1::##X;
    #include "valores.def"
  }

  throw std::runtime_exception("valor no valido");
}
```

Ventajas de este sistema:

- Los enumerados pueden estar en ficheros diferentes.
- Las utilidades no requieren mantenimiento
- Al utilizar macros, el contenido de `valores.def` puede ser todo lo versátil que queramos, pudiendo contener texto, comentarios, etc...
- Compatible con estándares antiguos de C++

Answer (score 1):

Una opción es usar el preprocesador.  Modificando tu ejemplo:

```
#define LISTA(X, S) \
X(A, 12) S \
X(B, 4) S \
X(C, 5)

#define COMA ,

// Este enumerado necesita los valores porque se almacenan en la base de datos
enum class Enum1
{
#define X(A, B) A = B
LISTA(X, COMA)
#undef X
};

// Este enumerado es necesario para realizar tareas de iteración
// y porque si :)
enum class Enum2
{
  NoValue,
#define X(A, B) A,
LISTA(X, )
#undef X
  MaxValues
};

// Convierte cada etiqueta en su representación a string
std::string ToString(Enum1 valor)
{
  switch( valor )
  {
#define X(A, B) case Enum1::A: return #A;
LISTA(X, )
#undef X
  }

  return "";
}

Enum1 FromString(std::string const& valor)
{
#define X(A, B) if (valor == #A) return Enum1::A;
LISTA(X, )
#undef X

  throw std::runtime_exception("valor no valido");
}

Enum1 Convert(Enum2 value)
{
  switch( value )
  {
#define X(A, B) case Enum2::A: return Enum1::A;
LISTA(X, )
#undef X
  }

  throw std::runtime_exception("valor no valido");
}
```